# Ant script build time vs. Eclipse build time

Tags: eclipse, ant

Exporting a project as a runnable jar takes approx 30sec to build, the (auto created) Ant script that does the same takes about 10 minutes to build.

What am I missing?

Comment: At least, you missed to show us your `Ant` script!

Comment: Unfortunately, my crystal ball is away for maintenance in preparation for halloween. So kindly post your ant script, so we can see if we spot a problem.

Comment: i think that this is ant script independent since i can reproduce that phenomen with all my eclipse projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create things from Eclipse all components are already compiled whereas if you do this via a ant script everything must be compiled from the scratch so i would expect differences in compile/build time.

Comment: is there any way to speed it up?

Comment: If you're absolutely positively sure that Eclipse has everything compiled (Project/Build Automatically is turned on), you can skip compiling in Ant entirely, but it's definitely not something I'd recommend. However, you can try it to test if that's the issue.